# The Usage Of Roll Back

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have some question about a questionable [headline](http://news.morningstar.com/all/market-watch/TDJNMW20140910327/update-obama-to-say-us-will-lead-broad-coalition-to-roll-back-islamic-state.aspx):

> Obama to say U.S. will lead broad coalition to ***roll back Islamic State***

According to dictionaries, "*roll back*" means to undo an action that was done.  The "*Islamic State*" is not not an action.  It is an organization or some pseudo-government in the middle east.   So, could the headline be poorly written?

Comment: Duplicate of meatie's original deleted question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33271/roll-back-islamic-state

Comment: But it is an organization or pseudo-gorvernment that has come into being through some action of theirs.  The US intends to undo that action so that they cease to exist.

Comment: This Wikipedia article might be helpful - [Rollback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollback), also the definition in M-W [Rollback](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rollback) "the act of reversing or undoing something".

Comment: [Discussion on meta.](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/is-it-okay-for-users-to-delete-questions-and-re-ask-them-verbatim)

Answer (score 2):

According to The Free Dictionary, "roll back" can also mean to return something to someone by rotating it, as with a wheel or a ball, or moving it back on wheels.  There is also the sense of "rolling back" the mileage on a car's odometer.  I understood the headline in the sense of moving the Islamic State's power back to 0, or back from prominence to non-existence.

Answer (score 2):

Another meaning of "roll back something" is to limit or reduce the effect or influence of something (Please refer to Cambridge dictionary - English grammar today). I think the statement is quite clear with this meaning of roll back.

Comment: Indeed. In the UK, right-wing politicians often like to say they will [roll back the state](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22roll+back+the+state%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (i.e. - reduce the extent to which government bureaucracy impinges on the citizenry).